# How to import CA cert for Chromium in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, chromium, ssl

I am able to import a certificate authority to the NSS Shared DB for use in Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04 and it works following these instructions in Chromium docs: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_cert_management.md

```
apt-get install libnss3-tools
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n comodoca -i comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt
```

However, when I try the same thing in Ubuntu 18.04, it does not work. The cert will not show up in Chrome Settings -> Manage Certificates -> Authorities tab.

One odd thing I noticed when I tried the same command was that the `$HOME/.pki/nssdb` dir did not exist in 18.04.

How can I programmatically import the CA cert for use in Chromium on Ubuntu 18.04?